# Bind value to combo box from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind a value to a combo box from the controller and I am getting the error that 'ControlColumn' of undefined.

```
<md-select ng-model="selected.pdfControl" ng-change="changePdfControl(selected.pdfControl)" required ng-disabled="!pdfFile">
    <md-option ng-repeat="pdfControl in pdfControls" ng-value="pdfControl">{{pdfControl.ControlColumn}} - {{pdfControl.ControlText}}</md-option>
</md-select>

$scope.selected.pdfControl.ControlColumn = "Test";
```

When I bind different value from the same event everything is OK

```
<md-input-container>
    <input ng-model="pdfVertical" required name="pdfVertical">
</md-input-container>

$scope.pdfVertical = "1234";
```

Comment: it will be easy if you can share more js code

Comment: @user6934713 will it help if i give you a general example how to bind the md-select with data from controller?

Comment: @user6934713 here is the plunk https://embed.plnkr.co/aYLTM49mpwuH2QM6aYZ8/